# mySQL Docker "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"

Tags: mysql, sockets, docker

got a little script to pull up some mySQL server variants and test my scripts on different versions. My shellscript is:

```
docker pull mysql:$version
docker run -d -v $(pwd)/mysql.sh:/mysql.sh --name=mysql."$version" -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='root' mysql:"$version"
docker exec -it mysql."$version" bash -c 'bash ./mysql.sh'
```

The mysql.sh file is:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart || service mysql restart || service mysqld restart
mysql -proot -e "SELECT @@version"
```

I get the following error:

```
./mysql.sh: line 1: /etc/init.d/mysql: No such file or directory
mysql: unrecognized service
mysqld: unrecognized service
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: I have not tried docker. But I see one error in mysql.sh file. Looks like it required minor correction to /etc/init.d/mysqld restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

docker does not use init.d structure for the services since it has no services. If you check inside the Dockerfile, you'll see that the mysql is started in foreground.

In your first script, the command `docker exec -it mysql."$version" bash -c 'bash ./mysql.sh'` is not needed. You should replace it with:

```
docker exec -it mysql."$version" mysql -proot -e "SELECT @@version"
```

Comment: Indeed, that's correct - seems like my misstake was that I was doing the commands to rapidly one after next, so it was simply too fast and the mysql server within the docker container wasn't up yet ... at least that's what I think it was. I have put in a sleep between the run and the exec - and now it works ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that  `/etc/init.d/mysql` is not found. You need to change that to `/usr/bin/mysql` and it should work.